# How to support count argument in a custom VIM text object?

Tags: vim

I have a custom text object that is defined by a function:

```
onoremap <buffer> <silent> <leader>M :<C-U>call MyFunction()<CR>
" MyFunction() selects the text in visual mode
```

Simple text operations like `d<leader>M` work well. Is there a way to make it work with a count argument (e.g. `d5<leader>M`)? The expected result would be calling `MyFunction()` five times, and deleting the selected text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After referring to [these instructions](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_2%29) I came up with the below snippet that should help you with your problem:

```
function! Hello()
    normal iHello, World^M^[
endfunction
map <F7> @=':call Hello()<C-V><CR>'<CR>
```

Pressing `F7` will insert "Hello, World\n" at the cursor location. `2F7` will insert "Hello, World\nHello,World\n" and so on.

Comment: Thanks! It does not work in this form because @= does not work in operator-pending mode. However, I found the solution in the linked article: the v:count variable contains the counter argument, so I can use it in MyFunction().